# How to do stuff like user.posts in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a **Post** model and a **User** model. Post belongs to user and User can have many posts:

```
 => #<Post id: 1, title: "First post", content: "first post", created_at: "2013-07-07 17:30:55", updated_at: "2013-07-07 17:30:55", user_id: 1> 
1.9.3-p0 :015 > user
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Jano", email: "jano@gmail.com", created_at: "2013-07-07 17:31:41", updated_at: "2013-07-07 17:31:41">
```

`post.user` works so far:

```
1.9.3-p0 :016 > post.user
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Jano", email: "jano@gmail.com", created_at: "2013-07-07 17:31:41", updated_at: "2013-07-07 17:31:41"> 
1.9.3-p0 :017 >
```

But when I do `user.posts`:

```
1.9.3-p0 :017 > user.posts
  Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 
1.9.3-p0 :018 >
```

I don't get the posts but a strange `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` thing.

I think I never saw this on Rails 3. Is there any different way of calling `user.posts` in Rails 4?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the actual results inside the console, you should add `to_a` on to the end:

```
user.posts.to_a
```

Comment: Oh thanks, but for the actual application I don't have to add to_a right?

Comment: Strange, I'm still getting an empty array: ` Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
 => [] `

Comment: The empty array would mean there are no posts for that user_id

Comment: It's not a matter of production vs development; it's just that `user.posts` usually won't be evaluated/executed until you actually use it (e.g. `user.posts.each`, etc.)